# Populate .yml file dynamically in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml, config, embedded-ruby

I want to populate my .yml file in config folder dynamically when my server is loading.

The following is an example of my .yml file

```
# Configuration Credentials

development: &development
  user: "***"
  password: "***" 

test:
  <<: *development

non-prod:
  user: "***"
  password: "***" 

production: &production
  user: "***"
  password: "***"
```

I want to set the value for each key in the form of embedded ruby like this:

```
development: &development
  user: <%= get_value_for(user)  %>
  password: <%= get_value_for(password)  %>
```

I want to load the .yml file when the server is about to run.

I want to know where should I define the get_value_for method so I can call it inside my yml file? (probably in application.rb but I do not know how exactly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom class and define the method their. Then require the class inside `config/application.rb`

```
# app/global/database_details.rb
class DatabaseDetails

  def self.get_value_for(user)
  end
end
```

Inside `config/application.rb`

```
require_relative '../app/global/database_details'

module AppName
  class Application < Rails::Application

  end
end
```

Inside `config/database.yml`

```
development: &development
  user: <%= DatabaseDetails.get_value_for(user)  %>
  password: <%= DatabaseDetails.get_value_for(password)  %>
```